# Can the imageView of UITableViewCell be set separately for selected and highlighted states?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview, uibutton

In UIButton the following method explicitly allows setting different images for different states:

```
// default is nil. should be same size if different for different states
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;
```

(1) Can something similar be done for UITableViewCell as well? For example by toggling certain states to true and then setting the imageView?

```
// set selected state (title, image, background). default is NO. animated is NO
@property(nonatomic,getter=isSelected) BOOL         selected;
// set highlighted state (title, image, background). default is NO. animated is NO
@property(nonatomic,getter=isHighlighted) BOOL      highlighted;
```

(2) Will the changes stick around or will the singular imageView simply be overwritten?

(3) What is the best way to emulate the image-per-state behavior in a table cell?

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to implement those booleans. UITableViewCell has a '[selected](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW8)' property that you can set to YES when the user selects a cell.
2. Your [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) callback - tableView [didSelectRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW14) should be used to set the image of the cell (I do this by setting the image of a UIImageView added as a subview to the cell's contentView) as shown:

   [cell.contentView addSubview:yourImageView];

You probably want to keep a track of the last cell which was set to the selected state. This could be done by storing the NSIndexPath of the cell that was previously selected. In didSelectRowForIndexPath, read this indexpath first, grab the corresponding cell and set it's image to be the unselected one.

I suggest subclassing UITableViewCell for this so that you can implement a method that takes in a UIImageView as an argument and sets it on the UIImageView set to be the cell's background image.

The code should all look like this:

The image setting method in your subclassed UITableViewCell:

```
- (void)setCellBackgroundImage:(UIImage*)inImage
{
    backgroundImageView.image = inImage;
}
```

Note that 'backgroundImageView is the UIImageView ivar that you will be using in your subclassed UITableViewCell. When you set up your cell, add this image view to your cell's contentView as shown previously.

Once your cell is set up with that method, your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method should look something like this (note that oldSelectedCell is of type NSIndexPath that holds the indexpath of your old selected cell):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"path/to/your/selected/image.png"];
    UIImage *deSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"path/to/your/deselected/image.png"];

    if(oldSelectedCell != nil)
    {
        //Assuming SubclassedCell is the name of your subclass of UITableViewCell
        SubclassedCell *cell = (SubclassedCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldSelectedCell];

        //Set the previously selected cell's image to be the deselected image
        [cell setCellBackgroundImage:deSelectedImage];

        //Set the cell to be deselected
        cell.selected = NO;
    }

    //Set the current cell's image
    SubclassedCell *cell = (SubclassedCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setBackgroundImage:selectedImage];
    cell.selected = YES;

    //Save this cell's indexpath to be the previously selected cell for the next time this method is invoked
    oldSelectedCell = indexPath;

    //And you're done!
}
```

The 'selected' property of the cell can be used to set up it's views as you like in the [layoutSubviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW27) implementation of your subclassed cell. Check the value of that property and set up your cell as you like.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough explanation! I've read it & I understand it so I'll vote back after putting it into effect and testing if it works out :)